# trying to show the random words but cannot show double

Tags: javascript

i have an array that contains 5 of words. I'm about to show the random words from an array but can't duplicate and by clicking the button. for example, 'js','css','php','java','html'

```
words=['html','css','js','php','java'];
var currentWords=0;
var targetWords=words.length;
var temp=[];

while(currentWords < targetWords){
        var randomQue=Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        console.log(randomQue)

        //check if the question already shown or not 
        if (temp[randomQue]){
             
        } else {
        }

        
        currentWords++;
        

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        let words=['html','css','js','php','java'];
        let selects = [];
        while(selects.length < words.length) {
            let for_select = (words.filter(x => !selects.includes(x)))
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * for_select.length)
            selected = for_select[index];
            console.log(selected);
            selects.push(selected);
        }
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let words = ['html','css','js','php','java'];
let currentWords = 0;
let targetWords = words.length;
let duplicates = [];

while(currentWords < targetWords) {
   let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
   console.log(randomIndex);

   let word = words[randomIndex];

   if (duplicates.includes(word)) {
      continue; //continues loop without adding to the duplicates or word count
   } else {
      duplicates.push(word);
      ++currentWords;
   }
}
```

Comment: i did try before i posted to this platform. I've got stucked. :(

Comment: why if is necessary? and you didn't remove it?

Comment: ...huh?  I'm not sure what you're asking  And @Michie, I'm saying try the solution I posted above

Comment: I think you can remove **if(...) continue;**, hum I think